# WP Woocommerce - No shipping tax added via api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to programmatically create a order using the WC API v3.
The order is created successfuly but the shipping line is added without tax.
However the total tax is calculated right.
If I just save the order in the backend the total tax gets reduced.
If I hit the calculate tax button WC adds the tax to the shipping line and everything is correct.

[image]

'MwSt.' stands for VAT and 'Versand' is shipping

This is my request object

```
 $order = (object) array(
      'order' => (object) array (
        'status' => 'pending',
        'payment_details' => (object) array(
          'method_id' => 'bacs',
          'method_title' => 'Überweisung',
          'paid' => FALSE,
        ),
        'billing_address' => (object) $billing_address,
        'shipping_address' => (object) $shipping_address,
        'customer_id' => $post->post_author,
        'line_items' => $line_items,
        'shipping_lines' => array(
          (object) array(
            'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
            'method_title' => 'Versandkostenpauschale',
            'total' => 5
          )
        )
      )
    );
```

I tried using WC_Order methods like calculate_totals, calculate_taxes and update_taxes.

Am I missing something? Or is there an easy way to trigger the action of the calculate tax button?

---

My solution:
Update the order item meta using this code

```
foreach($res->order->shipping_lines as $shipping_line) {
  wc_update_order_item_meta($shipping_line->id, 'taxes', array(1 => (string)round((5 / 100 * 19), 4)));
}
```

It's importent that you index the tax array with 1

Comment: Try using the method `add_tax()`. The params are `add_tax( integer $tax_rate_id, $tax_amount = 0, $shipping_tax_amount = 0  )`. You can get the tax amount by using `calculate_taxes()`.

Comment: Sadly that didn't helped, it adds a second tax column but the tax for the shipping line item is still empty.
I looked in the db table 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta' and I found out that the taxes array for the shipping line item is empty but the 'shipping_tax_amount' is set correctly. I will now try to update the tax array of line item now